# How to setup Facebook App Request from Unity with Prime31 Social combo plugin?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, apprequests, facebook-app-requests, prime31

my problem is this, when the user is asked to select friends from the list and click on Send I receive a Success state from callback but no request is reached from the people selected in the list.

My setup is this:
- my app is a native app for iOS and Android made in Unity
- my app is registered in Facebook developer portal as Game/Puzzle, I set up bundle id, package name, display name and namespace
- my app is not yet published
- I configured the Prime31 Facebook plugin with the appId given from Facebook and Display Name

I send my request like this:

```
public void AskLifesOnFacebook()
{

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        //{ "app_id", "#######my_app_id_number####" },
        { "method", "apprequests" },
        { "title", "My request title" },
        { "message", "My request text" }

    };
    FacebookCombo.showDialog("apprequests", parameters);
}
```

But still the friends selector is shown up correctly on an overlay windows, I select friends and send the request but no request is received.

Am I missing something in the configuration of my app on Facebook? Do I need to pass some kind of certification?

From the same app the stream.publish is working correctly and I can publish on user walls.

Comment: you cant get the globe notification on facebook unless you make your app for facebook canvas, otherwise the requests go to games then requests on the left side of facebook

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right way!
When your app is a native iOS app, the users see the notifications only the Facebook iOS app, so they are guarantee they can open iTunes or run the game.
Global (ej: regular browser on PC) are seen if the app is in a Facebok Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The setup with Prime31 plugin and the call are correct!
You have to enable "Single Sign On" and "Deep Linking" in Facebook app parameters and add a valid itunes ID for your app (while testing you can put any valid ID, but you should create a itunes connect entry for your app and get the final ID).
When your app is a native iOS app, the users see the notifications only through the Facebook iOS app, so they are guarantee they can open iTunes or run the game. 
Global notifications instead (ej: regular browser on PC) are seen if the app is in a Facebook Canvas.